# How to assign an integer value to "key.data" in Berkeley DB using C

Tags: c, berkeley-db

Off lately I am working with Berkeley DB. I have seen examples wherein people have used "string" as values to "key.data" while creating a database using Berkeley DB. I want to assign an integer value to it. How can I do that? Should I create a structure with int member in it or is there any other way possible?

```
DBT key, data;
memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key));
memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));
key.data = "fruit";
key.size = sizeof("fruit");
```

So instead of "fruit" above I want to assign an integer value. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> DBT structures provide a void * field that you use to point to your
>   data, and another field that identifies the data length. They can
>   therefore be used to store anything from simple primitive data to
>   complex structures so long as the information you want to store
>   resides in a single contiguous block of memory.

See, http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/gsg/C/DBEntry.html

To store integers, you would assign a pointer to an int to key.data, e.g.:

```
int x = 42;
key.data = &x;
key.size = sizeof(x);
```

Comment: Won't that cause problems if you read the database file on a system with different byte ordering?

Comment: @bromfiets: i used the method you showed above....but when I am trying to print it....it returns me a different value if ((ret = dbp->put(dbp, NULL, &key, &data, 0)) == 0)
   { printf("db: %d: key stored.\n", (char*)&key.data);}

Comment: @user537670 With &key.data you are taking the address of the pointer key.data. This is not necessary. key.data is already a pointer; cast it to be a pointer to an int and deference it, for example printf("key: %d\n", *(int *) key.data);

Comment: @Keith Yes it does. You would have to take care of byte ordering in the application, e.g. always read and write in a certain byte order.